How to get g++ to find .so files?
Seemingly as simple as can be: I want to link a shared object file and use a function from it. However, I can't even get this to work in the following simple use case:
In the directory /my_proj I have the files: my_func.cpp, my_func.hpp and main.cpp. Their contents:

my_func.hpp:

#ifndef MY_FUNC
#define MY_FUNC

int my_add(int a, int b);

#endif


my_func.cpp:

int my_add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}


main.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "my_func.hpp"

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    int sum = my_add(a, b);
    std::cout << "a + b = " << sum << ", thank you! <3" << std::endl;
}

If I simply compile both main.cpp and my_func.cpp, I get an executable that works perfectly.
However, if I create a .so for my_func like this:
g++ my_func.cpp -shared -o my_func.so

And then try to link to it like this:
g++ main.cpp -L. -lmy_func -o main

I get this error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmy_func
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I made sure the paths I'm using are correct, and tried both relative and absolute paths. I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the directory with the .so file, and then compiling with and without the -L argument. I've tried to set -L to both the .so itself and to the dir that contains it. I've tried to use an .so from an existing source and not just one I created myself. I've compiled directly with the source files instead of with a .so generated from them and got the code to work.
I must be missing something extremely basic here... how does linking an so file with g++ actually work?

-lmy_func looks for libmy_func.so. Do you guess now what name should be at -o in the first command?

You could try using a build system such as CMake, would make your life easier in the long run.

@3CxEZiVlQ yes! that worked, thank you so much!
